# Function in array is null in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I am having trouble with writing functions in arrays.

Here is what happens:

`config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  transformers: {
    reshape: {
      parser: 'sugarml',
      plugins: [
        // require('reshape-custom-elements')({defaultTag: 'span'})
        function () {
          console.log(arguments)
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the node REPL

`var config = require('./config.js')`

`console.log(JSON.stringify(config.transformers, null, 2))`

It outputs

```
{
  "reshape": {
    "parser": "sugarml",
    "plugins": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "uglify-js": {
    "mangle": {
      "toplevel": true
    }
  },
  "rollup": {
    "format": "es",
    "plugins": {
      "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": {},
      "rollup-plugin-commonjs": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I am confused why `plugins` is `[null]`

Comment: How do you expect a function to be serialized to JSON?

Comment: It is not JSON if i require() it as a JS file, right? It is still a JS object

Comment: It **is** JSON as soon as you pass it (successfully) through `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Oh, right. I have an error that I thought was related to this, but it wasn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot serialize a function in JSON. From MDN:

> If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array). JSON.stringify can also just return undefined when passing in "pure" values like JSON.stringify(function(){}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)

I would question storing configuration like this in JSON, but if you *really* need to you can consider something like [serialize-javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-javascript) that will handle the serialization of functions.